what is the meaning of" was the record not pressed yet?"
I have closed my dispute, now you can send it . Could you please send it after xmas . Btw did you forget to send it or was the record not pressed yet?
was the record not pressed yet   Does this sentence mean the record should have been pressed at that specific time

A record pressing describes the creation of vinyl music records. It means the physical process by which the music tracks are copied from the master disc onto new discs. But that can't be the meaning here. I'm guessing the word should be processed. eg, an invoice is processed for a sale or for services rendered.

The word yet there means "as of (the date the item should have been shipped)". One would infer from that statement that the speaker believes it was possible that the seller was taking  advance orders, and there is the further possible implication that the record would be pressed (manufactured) only when the seller had received enough orders to justify the setup costs.

You need to write your questions properly. This site is not a texting site. It makes it really hard to deal with them.  Your examples cannot be recognized as sentences as the punctuation is not right.

The process of manufacturing vinyl records is called pressing. This is because the physical image is pressed into the disc.
Without the context, your quote sounded to me like a complaint from someone trying to buy a record, perhaps from somewhere like eBay or similar. The seller is late sending the record, and the buyer is sarcastically asking if the record hasn't been pressed yet, as if that is the excuse for it not being sent.
Update - you have since explained that these are your own words and you want to know the meaning of what you said. If you have actually ordered a record before it was even pressed then your words would be taken at face value, and not sarcastically. However, "did you forget" could sound a little accusatory, and coupled with the get-out option of "or was has the record not been pressed yet" could come over as passive-aggressive.

In fact I worried (now I am not) because the record should have been pressed and ready to be shipped  at a date they did not respect, so I was wondering what happened but I would not be sarcastically

@YvesLefol Wait - so this is something you said, and you want to know what it means?

@Astralbee The process is called "pressing" because the grooves are pressed into the vinyl using heat and pressure in a die press or pressing machine.

no i was not sure that what I wrote meant what I wanted to express, I did not want to be sarcastic

@YvesLefol Ok I've updated my answer to include both possibilities.

but in fact  I would like to know why the record was not sent sooner and  asked the seller why;. Two reasons came to mind either  he forgot to send  or the record was not ready- maybe  not even  pressed at  the time (but my concern was not the pressing  itself but why it had not been sent sooner

"...or is the record not available yet?" (That is, manufactured and ready for sale.)

no, was , not is, because at the time he answered i already knew that the record had been sent

may be "was the record still unavailable " would be better here
